# Why type(nil)==nil is false?

Tags: lua, null

I'm reading "Programming in Lua" book and I don't understand exercise 2.1:

> What is the value of the expression
>
> type(nil)==nil?
>
> (You can use Lua to check your answer.) Can you explain this result?"

When I execute this code I get "false" as result. I could not explain this result, from my point of view correct result should be "true". I tried

```
type(some_undeclared_variable)==nil
```

and it also gives me "false".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function [`type()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-type) always returns a string, the value of `type(nil)` is the string `"nil"`, which is not the same as `nil`, they have different type.